# Play audio tag with javascript in firefox/internet explore/chrome

Tags: javascript, html

http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html

I'm trying to accomplish a sound script from above link, which should play a audio file. The article author claim it's compatible in firefox. But it's not playing in mine. It does however works in Chrome. Tried internet explore and not luck there either.

Are there any obvious reasons for this?

```
   <audio id="audiotag1" src="path.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
   <a href="javascript:play_single_sound();">Play 5-sec sound on single channel</a>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function play_single_sound() {
            document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
        }
   </script>
```

Comment: Plays fine for me in Firefox (45.0.1), with a test wav file I downloaded. And the page you linked to, also works. My Chrome plays it also. IE11 won't, but then that's no surprise. I wouldn't trust IE to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

[IE 11](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp) does not support `.wav` files, so if you want to support IE you'll have to use either `.mp3` or `.ogg`. As for why it didn't work in Firefox, a problem might be that `.wav` files are very large so depending on when you clicked on the link the audio file may not have loaded yet.

It's better to use the `canplay` event so you know when the audio file has loaded and can be played.

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audiotag1');
audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
  audio.play();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IE are you testing it on?

> IE often lags in terms of support for features.

Check out this [chart](https://html5test.com/results/desktop.html). Maybe your version of IE doesn't have support for audio.

---

**UPDATE**

> Adding this meta tag might help

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

> Installing [MediaPack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744) might help too

Comment: I'm using version 11. And the audio tag got a "yes" https://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie-11.html

Comment: And you're sure the path to your wav file is correct? What format of audio are you trying to play?

Comment: yea it should be correct, because it plays in chrome just fine. it's a wav file. It's probably the format? I should probably try a mp3

Comment: It did not help. But it works with mp3. So I'll re-record my audio. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @PushALU do post an answer once you solve it though!

Answer (score 0):

Were using .wav, tried with .mp3 and it works in all three browsers.